# how to Pass arguments from Controller.js to Service.js Furthur to MVC Controller

Tags: angularjs

*how do i pass arguments to Service Method*
please help, Your Help will be appreciated

**Controller.js**

```
$scope.dosome=function(){
        var txt1= document.getElementById("bid");
        var txt2=document.getElementById("bname");
        var txt3=document.getElementById("bau");
        LibraryService.donesome().then(function(txt1,txt2,txt3){
        });
    };

**Service.js**
 var donesome = function (txt1, txt2, txt3)
    {
        return $http.post("/Home/del"+txt1+txt2+txt3)
    }

**MVC Controller**
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult del( int txt1,string txt2,string txt3)
        {
            LibraryDatabaseEntities2 dc = new LibraryDatabaseEntities2();
            dc.proc1(txt1,txt2,txt3);
            dc.SaveChanges();
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplay inject your variable to the invoked method.

```
     $scope.dosome=function(){
                var txt1= document.getElementById("bid");
                var txt2=document.getElementById("bname");
                var txt3=document.getElementById("bau");
                LibraryService.donesome(txt1,txt2,txt3).then(function(response){
console.log(response);
                });
            };
```

I believe  this will work for you.
But I am not aware for where you `LibraryService.` is getting called ,i am just assuming it as the name of your service.

Comment: LibraryService is the name of service.js file, donsome() is function Out there and its not calling the donesome,  i m asking that why dosome is not calling donesome()

Comment: i have edited my answer instead of passing parameters in promise function inject it into service method.

Comment: can you modify the Service.js?? Error::TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: can you please provide your whole code on fiddle or plunkr ?

Comment: it database(EF) connectivity, so , its little difficult to provide code on fiddler, mail id will be appreciated so that i can send you whole application

Comment: you can take your data resource out put into a variable ,use a dummy JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Amoeba's telling you the correct way to pass the parameters to your service.
In your service, $http.post 2nd parameter is a data object. So do it like this:

```
    var data = { txt1: txt1, txt2: txt2, txt3: txt3 };
    return $http.post("/Home/del", data);
```

Your mvc controller will pick this up.